# 802.1ad (QinQ) and router

Tags: router, vlan, qinq

I am a little bit confused.

Is router aware of VLAN tag? What happen when tagged frame comes to router? (without any extra setting like encapsulation)

Or what happen when QinQ frame comes to router?

Will the router drop it or send it to the right network?

Thanks

Comment: Routers strip off and discard the data-link frame in order to route the packet, which is the payload of the frame. The packet is then routed based on the destination address in the packet header, and a new frame is generated for the network used by the interface to which the packet is switched.

Comment: Depends on the router and how it has been configured. 'tho in general, QinQ is something one normally does with switches (being L2)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Routers have physical interfaces that match the media they are connected to.  So a router connected to an Ethernet link that is using Q-in-Q would normally have the correct configuration (and logical interfaces) to match the VLANs it will route.

A misconfigured router would likely drop the frame, as it would be unable to interpret it.